# Broken Macro -- Find Last Row and Add Data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm so close, but this isn't working quite yet.

What's wrong here?

```
Sub DUMMY_ITEMS()
'
' DUMMY_ITEMS Macro
Sheets("Operations").Select
Range("H2:V73").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Raw Data").Select

Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub '
```

Comment: It would be easier if you tell us.  What error message are you getting?  On which line does the error occur?  What isn't working as you would expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean you got an error trying to use the `PasteSpecial` line.

As a recommendation, try to avoid using `Select`, `Selection`, and `ActiveSheet`, instead use fully qualified `Worksheets` and `Range`s.

**"Reduced" Code**

```
Sub DUMMY_ITEMS()
'
' DUMMY_ITEMS Macro
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("Operations").Range("H2:V73").Copy

With Sheets("Raw Data")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Shai_Rado. I upvoted, but my reputation is too low to  register. Really appreciate your help!